# Unable to fetch view `get_swap_min_res` from quipuswap v2 pool using smartpy

Tags: smartpy

I was trying to use views in the v2 contract of quipuswap. This is my code.

But getting the error while executing.
Can someone spot where I am going wrong?

Code:

```
    @sp.entry_point
    def get_swap_details(self):
        swap_details = sp.view('get_swap_min_res', 
                                self.data.dex_address, 
                                sp.record(
                                    swaps = [
                                                sp.record(
                                                    direction = sp.variant("a_to_b", sp.unit),
                                                    pair_id = sp.nat(0)
                                                )
                                            ],
                                    amount_in = sp.nat(1000000)
                                ), 
                                t = sp.TNat
                        ).open_some("Something is Wrong here")

        self.data.current_price = swap_details
```

Error I am getting is

```
[
  {
    "kind": "temporary",
    "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.runtime_error",
    "contract_handle": "KT1EcQZB7kU3ihQbJqss7ypknbATM7j6Cbuz"
  },
  {
    "kind": "temporary",
    "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.script_rejected",
    "location": 36,
    "with": {
      "string": "Something is Wrong here"
    }
  }
]
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the issue of layouts.

The [get_swap_min_res](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1GPJDTf8GZspCcanaG2KhMvGu3NJRqurat/views) view in this contract takes the input in the following Michelson type:

```
(pair
    (list %swaps
        (pair (or %direction (unit %a_to_b) (unit %b_to_a))
        (nat %pair_id)))
    (nat %amount_in)
)
```

But in the above SmartPy contract, there is no mention of the Pair tree structure of the view's params record. So, SmartPy automatically creates a structure of the following form: [(line no. 10 here)](https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1HzBzRy5YHsLMU1D76QC1FrScShRuRKdZ4/code)

```
(pair nat (list (pair unit nat))) (Pair 1000000 { Pair Unit 0 })
```

This can be solved by explicitly telling SmartPy to use the exact layout which the other contract is expecting. Like this:

```
@sp.entry_point
def get_swap_details(self):
    get_swap_min_res_param_type = sp.TRecord(
        swaps = sp.TList(
            sp.TRecord(
                direction = sp.TVariant(
                    a_to_b = sp.TUnit,
                    b_to_a = sp.TUnit
                ),
                pair_id = sp.TNat
            ).layout(("direction", "pair_id"))
        ),
        amount_in = sp.TNat
    ).layout(("swaps", "amount_in"))

    get_swap_min_res_param = sp.record(
        swaps = [
            sp.record(
                direction = sp.variant("a_to_b", sp.unit),
                pair_id = sp.nat(0)
            )
        ],
        amount_in = sp.nat(1000000)
    )

    swap_details = sp.view('get_swap_min_res',
        self.data.dex_address,
        sp.set_type_expr(get_swap_min_res_param, get_swap_min_res_param_type), 
        t = sp.TNat
    ).open_some("Something is Wrong here")
    self.data.current_price = swap_details
```

Here, we set the type of this record using `sp.set_type_expr()`, more on this [here](https://smartpy.dev/docs/general/types#setting-a-type-constraint). This way it send the exact structure which we can check [here on line 10](https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1JQ2QaeTCfgcMFxPmGpCfkRoaUpcAMqGXw/code)